# search whit '/' character-[LUCENE.NET 4]

Tags: lucene.net

How to search with the character '/' within a text? IN LUCENE 4 (in version 3 it works) I describe the tests

## test1

**Lucene 4 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01/02/03"
"01/02/04"
"01/02/05"
```

**Lucene 4 search**

search `"01/02/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

## test2

**Lucene 3 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01/02/03"
"01/02/04"
"01/02/05"
```

**Lucene 3 search**

search `"01/02/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 1 hits

search `"01/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 3 hits

## test3

**Lucene 3 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01/02/03"
"01/02/04"
"01/02/05"
```

**Lucene 4 search**

search `"01/02/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 1 hits

search `"01/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 3 hits

NOTE:search for full text and test whit scape

## test4

**Lucene 4 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01\/02\/03"
"01\/02\/04"
"01\/02\/05"
```

**Lucene 4 search**

search `"01/02/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

## test5

**Lucene 4 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01\/02\/03"
"01\/02\/04"
"01\/02\/05"
```

**Lucene 4 search**

search `"01\/02\/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01\/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

## test6

**Lucene 4 index**

analizer: `StandAnalizer`

indeded values

```
"01/02/03"
"01/02/04"
"01/02/05"
```

**Lucene 4 search**

search `"01\/02\/05"` whit `TermQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01\/02*"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

search `"01"` whit `TermQuery` = 3 hits

search `"01**"` whit `WildCardQuery` = 0 hits

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to search with the character '/' within a text? IN LUCENE 4 (in version 3 it works) I describe the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TermQuery` with `SimpleAnalyzer` works just fine. I'm using Lucene.Net.4.8.0-beta00005. Here is an example:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void SearchByDate()
{
    using (RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory())
    {
        using (SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48))
        {
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, analyzer);

            Document[] documents = new Document[]
            {
                new Document { new StringField("Date", "01/02/03", Field.Store.YES), },
                new Document { new StringField("Date", "01/02/04", Field.Store.YES), },
                new Document { new StringField("Date", "01/02/05", Field.Store.YES), },
            };

            using (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config))
                foreach (Document document in documents)
                    writer.AddDocument(document);

            using (DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.Open(directory))
            {
                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
                TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("Date", "01/02/04"));

                ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.Search(query, 10).ScoreDocs;

                Assert.AreEqual(1, hits.Length);

                Document doc = searcher.Doc(hits.First().Doc);

                Assert.AreEqual("01/02/04", doc.Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Date").GetStringValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```